# How nav bar works in this php code using codeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is a source code of nav bar made using PHP framework CodeIgniter.I didn't understand login behind nav url of "Bulk Conversion" and "Login" which is given using site_url instead of `<a href = "bulk_conversion.php">` and `<a href = "login.php">`. How nav bar code works here?

```
<div class="header clearfix">
<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li role="presentation" class="{{ $_nav === 'batch' ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{ site_url('batch') }}">Bulk Conversion</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="{{ site_url('admin') }}">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: may b with codeigniter there is smarty also. and its simple code there is not any complication.

Comment: There's [documentation on site_url](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#site_url) available. "Bulk Conversion" links to `/batch`, "Login" links to `/admin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter is an object-oriented MVC framework. For the most part you don't make calls to .php files by name. Instead, CodeIgniter uses a segment-based approach to URLs with a one-to-one relationship between a URL string and its corresponding controller/method and optionally, parameters. Any URI segments after the first two are considered parameters (variables) passed to the controller's method. Find a better explanation of what I'm trying to explain in [the Documentation.](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

`site_url` is a CodeIgniter helper function that will construct a full URL from a URI string. So the call to `site_url('batch')` for a website on example.com will produce the string `http://example.com/batch`. This will result in the `index()` method of the controller `Batch` being executed.

The call `site_url('admin')` works the same except the `Admin` controller is being called.

Clear as mud?